# Storing boost::bind functions in a std::map

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, boost-bind, boost-function

I'm creating a bunch of functions which all effectively do the same thing:

```
long Foo::check(long retValue, unsigned toCheck, const std::set<unsigned>& s)
{
    auto it = s.find(toCheck);
    return (it == s.end()) ? -retValue : retValue;
}
```

where Foo is a class. All fairly simple so far. Now, I effectively want to create a lot of variants on this, but bound to different sets. I then want to store these in a std::map. So, using boost::bind and boost::function, do something like:

```
void Foo::addToMap(unsigned option, const std::set<unsigned>& currentSet)
{
    someMap[option] = boost::bind(&Foo::check, this, _1, _2, currentSet);
}
```

The problem I'm having is trying to define the type of the map. I thought it would be:

```
std::map<unsigned, boost::function<long (long, unsigned)> > someMap;
```

But compiling this with MSVC 9.0 gives: `error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'boost::function<Signature>'`.

What exactly should the second template argument to map be?

Comment: have you tried to wrap the set argument (to bind) in boost::ref or whatever it's called? references aren't assignable.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Tried wrapping it with boost::cref(currentSet) but that gives the exact same error. Same if I pass it by non-const, same if I pass it by non-const value...

Comment: oh, dang. then please try to reproduce the problem in a minimal program, and post that (complete code).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks. You indirectly helped me solve this, since by creating a minimal program, I realized I wasn't including the right header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I solved it. I was including the wrong header file; instead of:

`#include <boost/function.hpp>`

I was including things from the boost/function folder like:

`#include <boost/function/function_fwd.hpp>`

Answer (score 0):

Using boost 1.49 and g++ 4.4.4, I was able to do something very similar. Here is a code snippet.

```
typedef boost::function< void (SomeType) > CallbackType;

std::pair<std::string, CallbackType> NameCallbackPair;
```

I was then able to assign it with the following:

```
NameCallbackPair somePair(someString, boost::bind(&SomeClass::someMethod, this, _1));
```

Maybe it's something with MSVC9.